# keepassX autotype turns @ into 1/8

Tags: keepass

I'm using keepassx auto type functionality for different logins. When the username contains an "@" symbol the auto-type function turns the "@" into "1/8". In the db it correctly shows the "@" sign. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepassx/bugs/269/) you're facing an issue with wrong/multiple keyboard layouts. The solution suggested there is:

In case you need only one keyboard layout, using `setxkbmap <LanguageCode>` should work.

In case you are actually working with multiple keyboard layouts, there seems to be no solution except configuring only a single layout.